# Image does not update when file name remains the same in XCode 3.1.2

Tags: image, xcode, load

I'm using XCode version 3.1.2 and am developing for iPhone using the Simulator with iOS 2.2.1 on Leopard. I had an image file named "img.jpg" in my project which I decided to switch for a different file. After adding the new file into the XCode Resources folder, I removed the first file and renamed the new file to the same name as the previous one, "img.jpg." When I run my program, however, the Simulator loads the old image instead of the new one, even though the old one has been deleted from disk (not just the reference). I tried changing the name of the file to "img2.jpg," and it worked like it should - loading the new image, but I want to keep the name "img.jpg." I ran a search with Spotlight for "img.jpg" to see if there was another copy stored somewhere that XCode was using, but it only returned my new image file. I have tried uninstalling the app from the Simulator and running the application again, but that also does not fix the problem.

What must I do for XCode to recognize that I want to use the new image file and not the old one?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Are you specifying the image in code through an `IBOutlet`? Or are you setting the image on a `UIImageView` in Interface Builder? Maybe it is specified in two places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should clean build all your XCode Projects Targets by using "Build" -> "Clean all targets", and rebuild from scratch. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a big project and don't want to wait that long, you can also remove and re-add the file reference from/to your project.  That seems to always work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve it by performing both routines:

1. Read the new images into Xcode

   > Product > Clean
2. Secondly update the simulator
   You also have to force sending the updated images to the simulator.
   You can do this by deleting the folders, or just removing the app from
   the simulator (as you normally do on your phone).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Xcode 4. The problem was caused by a Default~iphone.png hanging around with the old image. I saved the screen shot over Default~iphone.png and chose that file as the launch image in the project summary page. You can tell if this is your problem when you select the Default~iphone.png file as the iphone launch image and xcode asks you if you want to overwrite Default.png.

Answer (score 0):

An important addition - when working with Simulator, delete the folder in the Simulator

The folder must be named something like
/Users/*username*/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/53630E9A-6E04-4D33-8600-AD29484C9FA8
and have YourAppName.app inside